# SQL Query Where Date = Today Minus 7 Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, between

I have a SQL table of hits to my website called ExternalHits. I track the URL as URLx and the date the page was accessed as Datex. I run this query every week to get the count of total hits from the week before, and every week I have to manually change the "between" dates. Is there some way I can change my query so that the "between" dates are something like TODAY AND TODAY-7? Ijust want to not have to manually change the dates every week.

```
    SELECT URLX, COUNT(URLx) AS Count
    FROM ExternalHits
    WHERE datex BETWEEN '02/27/2017' AND '03/05/2017'    
    GROUP BY URLx
    ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Comment: If this is SQL Server, `BETWEEN CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, -7, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))`. You have conflicting tags. Is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: With the conflicting tags this is nearly impossible to answer. The syntax is vastly different between mysql and sql server.

Comment: Fixed. My bad. It's SQL Server.

Comment: Any technical reason why every answer suggest BETWEEN.  A hits table will never have a future date. Anything wrong with just  >  DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
declare @lastweek datetime
declare @now datetime
set @now = getdate()
set @lastweek = dateadd(day,-7,@now)

SELECT URLX, COUNT(URLx) AS Count
FROM ExternalHits
WHERE datex BETWEEN @lastweek AND @now
GROUP BY URLx
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Answer (score 13):

Using dateadd to remove a week from the current date.

```
datex BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can subtract 7 from the current date with this:

```
WHERE datex BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in functions:

```
SELECT URLX, COUNT(URLx) AS Count
FROM ExternalHits
WHERE datex BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY URLx
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

`WHERE datex BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to swap Between's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT URLX, COUNT(URLx) AS Count
FROM ExternalHits
WHERE datex BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()    
GROUP BY URLx
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Comment: is this MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Daysforward int
SELECT @Daysforward = 25 (no of days required)
Select * from table name

where CAST( columnDate AS date) < DATEADD(day,1+@Daysforward,CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

Answer (score 0):

For MariaDB:

```
WHERE datex BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

It helps me.