# How to get date of all days in past week?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have an application in which every Sunday, it checks a MySQL database for data from the past week.  I am trying to find out how to get the date String for each day of the past week.  My obvious first attempt was:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

if(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == 7){

    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

    String dates[] = new String[7];

    for(int i; i < 7; i++){
        dates[i] = date.substring(0,7) + date.substring(7, date.length());
    }

    // Now grab data from the database where the date corresponds with one of these.
}
```

Today, this would work.  However, if it were the 1st through the 6th of a month, this would not work as it wouldn't account for the change in month.  Is there a way to get around this.  I'm sure somebody has done a similar thing.  Thanks.

Comment: If you data is stored in the database as date types, then you should avoid using `String`s to represent them in your queries, favouring `PreparedStatement`s to bind the values to the parameters. If the data is not stored as date types - then you have a much larger issue at hand. You should also consider using the new and improved date/time API available in Java 8+

Comment: I do have it stored as a date type in my database, but I didn't know how else to manipulate a date.  I figured it would be put into a prepared statement anyways so it wouldn't matter whether String or Date.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I also recommend you don’t pass strings to your database query. Use `LocalDate` there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try different approach? like pass today's date to sql procedure and filter last 7 days at query level with where clause?

say where date is <= today-7

Comment: The issue is that today - 7 could result in a negative number if the date is the 1st through the 6th.

Comment: use dateadd() sql function with  -7. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635297/sql-query-where-date-today-minus-7-days

Comment: Perfect, `dateadd()` works.

Comment: Let me note that dateadd is for Microsoft SQL.  Use interval for MySQL.