# CASE statement that will mark data '1 week before'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I need a CASE statement that will be marking data that was one week before.  CASE statement that will mark data '1 week before'. it should basically mark rows where 'STARTDATE' is equals to one week before.
If today (1/13/2021) it should look at the data '1/2/2021' and return 'Data one week before'.
This column has only Sunday dates namely 1/02, 1/09 etc. I need this column to return value 'Data one week before' if it equals to 1/02 for example today.
This query should be dynamic and readjust itself each week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtUKW.jpg)

```
SELECT [DMDUNIT]
  ,[LOC]
  ,[MODEL]
  ,[JOBID]
  ,[USERID]
  ,[FCSTDATE]
  ,[STARTDATE] FROM [BYIntegration].[SCPOMGR].[FCSTPERFSTATIC]
```

Please let me know if someone knows how to do it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please also add your dbms

Comment: @Christophe I cannot make it dynamic that's why I ask. Obviously CASE WHEN [STARTDATE] = '1-02-2022' THEN '1 week before' ELSE 'Not relevant' END AS 'Date from prior week'  but this is not right because I need that '1-02-2022' to change every week.

Comment: See if you can work it out from the answer on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635297/sql-query-where-date-today-minus-7-days

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you, i know about DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE()) but I need to have a dynamic calculation in a sense that today we have Thursday, 1/13 but it needs to return not - 7 days but -11 days. At the same time, tomorrow it should return - 12 days. Next Sunday, 1/16/2021 it will be - 7 days. I need a dynamic calculation that will keep in mind that it needs to return Sunday of the prior week. I am not sure there is smth like that in that post

Comment: You're right that post does not have that logic. I suggest you post some clear sample data in a table rather than explaining in words. There are solutions to this on stackoverflow, which boil down to: work out what todays weekday is, and add that that the the offset days

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422248/previous-monday-previous-sundays-date-based-on-todays-date

Comment: My google search was "t-sql find prior sunday" and that was the first thing that came up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think something like this would work for you.

```
DECLARE @BeginningOfWeek VARCHAR(25) = 'Sunday'
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DaysToBeginningOfThisWeek INT = 0
DECLARE @BeginningOfInterval INT

WHILE @BeginningOfWeek <> DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY,-@DaysToBeginningOfThisWeek,@Today))
BEGIN
    SET @DaysToBeginningOfThisWeek = @DaysToBeginningOfThisWeek + 1
END

SET @BeginningOfInterval = 7 + @DaysToBeginningOfThisWeek

SELECT [DMDUNIT]
,[LOC]
,[MODEL]
,[JOBID]
,[USERID]
,[FCSTDATE]
,[STARTDATE]
,CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[STARTDATE])) 
<= DATEADD(DAY,-7,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@Today)) 
AND 
DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[STARTDATE])) 
> DATEADD(DAY,-@BeginningOfInterval,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@Today))
THEN 'One week before'
ELSE NULL END AS WeekBefore
FROM [BYIntegration].[SCPOMGR].[FCSTPERFSTATIC]
```

This assumes that STARTDATE includes a time. If not, the DATEDIFF part of the expression can be eliminated. That is, instead of "DATEADD(DAY,-7,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[STARTDATE]))", you would have "DATEADD(DAY,-7,[STARTDATE])". Like this:

```
SELECT [DMDUNIT]
,[LOC]
,[MODEL]
,[JOBID]
,[USERID]
,[FCSTDATE]
,[STARTDATE]
,CASE WHEN [STARTDATE]
<= DATEADD(DAY,-7,@Today) 
AND 
[STARTDATE] 
> DATEADD(DAY,-@BeginningOfInterval,@Today)
THEN 'One week before'
ELSE NULL END AS WeekBefore
FROM [BYIntegration].[SCPOMGR].[FCSTPERFSTATIC]
```